# Riemann Integral Estimation

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have been having difficulties with the following problem:

Show that $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{\sin(x)}{x(5+x)} dx < \frac{\pi}{10}.$

My attempt at a solution:
I know that $-1 \leq \sin(x) \leq 1$, and the denominator of the problem has a domain of $(-\infty, -5) \cup (-5, 0) \cup (0, \infty)$. One thing I could think of to use the Taylor series of $\sin(x)$ and divide each term accordingly, but I am not sure if this would be valid. In my textbook, this question follows from the Riemann Integral section.

I input $\frac{\pi}{10}$ into MATLAB and got a value of 0.314159265358979, which is also between $[-1,1]$. Any suggestions/advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Note: In class, we have not covered the Fundamental Theorems of Calculus, so I am not sure about evaluating this integral directly.

I am using the textbook *Introduction to Analysis* by Arthur Mattuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: you're making it too hard.  Look for more basic tricks first.  Use the fact that $\sin x  < x$ for $x>0$.   If you have to justify that, the Mean Value Theorem may do the trick.  Then use the comparison property of the definite integral.

Addtional hint: you don't have to know how to integrate $\frac{1}{5+x}$.  Use another comparison.

Comment: Would the comparison of $\ln (x)$ work since, using $\sin(x)<x, x>0, \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{(5+x)} dx < \displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{(x)} dx = \ln(x)$? Thank you very much for your suggestion.

Comment: @Jamil_V : that doesn't work because $1/x$ blows up at $x=0$.  Use $1/(5+x) < 1/5$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:
$$
\sin x<x \quad\mbox{ for }\quad x\in(0,\pi/2)
$$
$$
\log(1+x)< x \quad\mbox{ for }\quad x>0
$$